# Parsing a difficult json logs using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json file as shown below

{

```
"body": {

    "results": [

        [

            {

                "field": "@timestamp",

                "value": "2020-04-26 19:28:40.136"

            },

            {

                "field": "@message",

                "value": "Hi"

            },

            {

                "field": "@time",

                "value": "19:28:40,023"

            },

            {

                "field": "@name",

                "value": "Nitish"

            },

            {

                "field": "@hobby",

                "value": "Pool"

            },

            {

                "field": "@duration",

                "value": "19 mins"

            }



        ],

        [

            {

                "field": "@timestamp",

                "value": "2020-04-26 19:28:40.136"

            },

            {

                "field": "@message",

                "value": "Hello"

            },

            {

                "field": "@time",

                "value": "19:28:40,023"

            },

            {

                "field": "@name",

                "value": "Amuri"

            },

            {

                "field": "@Totalruns",

                "value": "2"

            },

            {

                "field": "@wickets",

                "value": "10"

            },

            {

                "field": "@hobby",

                "value": "cricket"

            },

            {

                "field": "@commentry",

                "value": "ubbjb"

            }

        ],

        [

            {

                "field": "@timestamp",

                "value": "2020-04-26 19:28:40.136"

            },

            {

                "field": "@message",

                "value": "how are you"

            },

            {

                "field": "@time",

                "value": "19:28:40,023"

            },

            {

                "field": "@name",

                "value": "Kit"

            },

            {

                "field": "@Totalruns",

                "value": "90"

            },

            {

                "field": "@wickets",

                "value": "1"

            },

            {

                "field": "@hobby",

                "value": "cricket"

            },

            {

                "field": "@commentry",

                "value": "jbunib"

            }

        ]

        ]

}
```

}

I'm trying to parse @Totalruns and @wickets only if @hobby = cricket

I'm able to reach till accessing cricket unable to figure out  to get data of @Totalruns and @wickets

code i've tried import json

```
f = open('/Users/amurin/Documents/test.json','r')

data = json.load(f)

for result in data['body']['results']:

    for res in result:

        if res['value']=='cricket':

            print("Hello")

f.close()
```

I need output as 
wickets = 1 , Totalruns = 90
wickets = 10 , Totalruns = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1, keeping the structure as it is:

```
def sublist_is_valid(sublist):
    return any(d["field"] == "@hobby" and d["value"] == "cricket" for d in sublist)


def filter_fields(sublist):
    return [d for d in sublist if d["field"] in ["@wickets", "@Totalruns"]]


filtered = [
    filter_fields(sublist)
    for sublist in data["body"]["results"]
    if sublist_is_valid(sublist)
]

print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
[[{'field': '@Totalruns', 'value': '2'}, {'field': '@wickets', 'value': '10'}],
 [{'field': '@Totalruns', 'value': '90'}, {'field': '@wickets', 'value': '1'}]]
```

### Solution 2 (better IMO) is to use dictionaries right from the beginning:

```
def sublist_to_dict(sublist):
    return {d["field"]: d["value"] for d in sublist}


filtered = [
    {key: d[key] for key in ["@Totalruns", "@wickets"]}
    for d in [sublist_to_dict(sublist) for sublist in data["body"]["results"]]
    if d.get("@hobby") == "cricket"
]

print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
[{'@Totalruns': '2', '@wickets': '10'}, {'@Totalruns': '90', '@wickets': '1'}]
```

Comment: Thankyou @Arnaud for unblocking me. I was stuck with this from past 24 hour